# undefined symbol: THPVariableClaload_textures.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: THPVariableClass

Tags: python, pytorch, shared-libraries, cpython

Do you know how I could fix this? I am trying to use https://github.com/benjiebob/SMALViewer/issues/3 repo however I get error on neural_renderer port:

```
$ python smal_viewer.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smal_viewer.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyqt_viewer
  File "/home/mona/research/3danimals/SMALViewer/pyqt_viewer.py", line 13, in <module>
    from smal.smal3d_renderer import SMAL3DRenderer
  File "/home/mona/research/3danimals/SMALViewer/smal/smal3d_renderer.py", line 6, in <module>
    import neural_renderer as nr
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neural_renderer/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .load_obj import load_obj
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neural_renderer/load_obj.py", line 8, in <module>
    import neural_renderer.cuda.load_textures as load_textures_cuda
ImportError: /home/mona/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: THPVariableClass
```

Here is some details:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.6.0'
>>> torch.version.cuda
'10.1'
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True


$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Here is the neural renderer git repo: https://github.com/daniilidis-group/neural_renderer

I installed the neural renderer using `pip install neural_renderer_pytorch`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you didn't build the `neural_renderer_pytorch` yourself, but used a wheel. However, this wheel was built with an older `pytorch` version and doesn't work with the current `pytorch` version on your machine.

Build `neural_renderer` from the source (after deinstalling `neural_renderer` you have now) using your current pytorch-version  i.e.

```
$ pip uninstall neural-renderer-pytorch

$ pip install https://github.com/daniilidis-group/neural_renderer/zipball/master
```

and it should work.

---

Until pytorch 1.5, it used a someway brittle way of building extensions on Linux: despite depending on [`torch`](https://github.com/daniilidis-group/neural_renderer/blob/b2a1e6ce16a54f94f26f86fe1dc3814637e15251/neural_renderer/cuda/create_texture_image_cuda.cpp#L1), extensions didn't link explicitly against `libtorch.so`. The missing symbols were provided only because `import torch` loaded `libtorch.so` with `RTLD_GLOBAL`, thus making its symbols globally visibile/accessible - this is the reason why prior to loading those extensions (e.g. `neural_renderer_pytorch` like [here](https://github.com/daniilidis-group/neural_renderer/blob/b2a1e6ce16a54f94f26f86fe1dc3814637e15251/neural_renderer/load_obj.py#L4)) one had to import `torch`.

One could enforce the old behavior setting `RTLD_GLOBAL` prior to importing `torch` for **the very first time** it is happening:

```
import sys; import ctypes;
sys.setdlopenflags(sys.getdlopenflags() | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
import torch # now all symbols of torch
             # have global visibility and can be used in 
             # other extensions
```

However, using `RTLD_GLOBAL` is quite dangerous as it could possibly interpose symbols that are unrelated and lead to subtle bugs or even crashes.

Thus, since 1.5 pytorch no longer uses `RTLD_GLOBAL`, but links explicitly against `libpytorch.so` (see this [commit](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/commit/86148602102e833cc2e04eca9707a53c3287f50c#diff-c0f5058d6a00dd25b52bcc8ba0a8b06dL449)) and extensions built with older pytorch versions will not work.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work https://pastebin.com/raw/Gfh4qFHE

Comment: @MonaJalal README (https://github.com/daniilidis-group/neural_renderer/blob/master/README.md#requirements) says that for newer versions one should try to use at_assert_fix-branch, i.e. `pip install https://github.com/daniilidis-group/neural_renderer/zipball/at_assert_fix`. I cannot check this, as I don't have a proper machine at hand. This project wasn't active for almost 2 years, so if the other branch doesn't work, your options are either to use workarounds or to use pytorch 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by first finding all the `AT_CHECK` and converting them to `AT_ASSERT`. Checking out the `at_assert_fix` branch didn't solve the problem for me. I am using PyTorch 1.6 and CUDA 10.1

https://github.com/daniilidis-group/neural_renderer/search?q=AT_CHECK

```
(base) mona@mona:~/neural_renderer/neural_renderer/cuda$ vi create_texture_image_cuda.cpp 
(base) mona@mona:~/neural_renderer/neural_renderer/cuda$ vi load_textures_cuda.cpp 
(base) mona@mona:~/neural_renderer/neural_renderer/cuda$ vi rasterize_cuda.cpp 

(base) mona@mona:~/neural_renderer$ pip install .
Processing /home/mona/neural_renderer
Building wheels for collected packages: neural-renderer-pytorch
  Building wheel for neural-renderer-pytorch (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for neural-renderer-pytorch: filename=neural_renderer_pytorch-1.1.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl size=6215781 sha256=fbd9e8ef7340fa71b9fcd69da8ee06a1079ebbe5b4c2c3ce92e8124bc8cea7c5
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-tddilaof/wheels/c6/9b/9b/d2cda4f9ac2127278c21ea5c5e23c3354fe0e63365b7af7842
Successfully built neural-renderer-pytorch
Installing collected packages: neural-renderer-pytorch
Successfully installed neural-renderer-pytorch-1.1.3
(base) mona@mona:~/neural_renderer$ python examples/example1.py 
Drawing: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 90/90 [00:04<00:00, 19.37it/s]
```

https://github.com/daniilidis-group/neural_renderer/issues/94